# NestJS class validator with IsEnum for prisma enum

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, nestjs, prisma

I have this restful application that I am making. The model in my prisma schema looks like below:

```
model Customers {
  id                    Int             @id @default(autoincrement()) @map("id")
  customerType          Customer_types  @relation(fields: [customer_type_id], references: [id])
  customer_type_id      Int             @map("customer_type_id")
  identification_number String          @unique @map("identification_number")
  customer_names        String          @map("customer_names")
  msisdn                String          @unique @map("msisdn")
  email                 String?         @unique @map("email")
  gender                CustomerGender @map("gender")
  customer_source       CustomerSource         @map("customer_source")
  created_at            DateTime        @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updated_at            DateTime        @updatedAt @map("updated_at")

  payments           Transactions[]
  services           Services[]
  customer_referrals Customer_referrals[] @relation("customer_id")
  referrals          Customer_referrals[] @relation("referree_id")
  addressess         Addresses[]

  @@map("qp_customers")
}

enum CustomerGender {
  Male
  Female
}

enum CustomerSource {
  Website
  Facebook
  Twitter
  Instagram
  TV
  Radio
  Walkin
  FieldVisit
}
```

I need to make it such that certain fields are limited, thus i use enums for gender and customer source.
On the Restful API I use a dto with class-validator. For this I use IsEnum classvalidator for gender and customer_source.

```
export class AuthDto {
  @IsEmail()
  @IsOptional()
  email: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  password: string;

  @IsInt()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  customer_type_id: number;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  msisdn: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  identification_number: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  customer_names: string;

  @IsInt()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  referree_id: number;

  @IsInt()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  user_id: number;

  @IsEnum(CustomerGender)
  @IsNotEmpty()
  gender: string;

  @IsEnum(CustomerSource)
  @IsNotEmpty()
  customer_source: string;
}
```

However I am getting this error:

```
src/auth/auth.service.ts:38:11 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'CustomerGender'.

38           gender: dto.gender,
             ~~~~~~

  node_modules/.prisma/client/index.d.ts:16658:5
    16658     gender?: CustomerGender | null
              ~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'gender' which is declared here on type '(Without<CustomersCreateInput, CustomersUncheckedCreateInput> & CustomersUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & CustomersCreateInput)'
```

The application is RESTFUL api. What could be the issue here. Even if I change the IsEnum to IsString the error remains. What could i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might have fixed this by now but I will post this answer in case someone else faces the same problem.

the problem is here

```
  @IsEnum(CustomerSource)
  @IsNotEmpty()
  customer_source: string;
```

you have assigned a type of CustomerSource to the enum validator but then below that, you have set the property to be of type string which are two different things thus the error:

```
 error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'CustomerGender'.
```

this should work:

```
  @IsEnum(CustomerSource)
  @IsNotEmpty()
  customer_source: CustomerSource;
```